# Get FTP virtual hostname in IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider.GetUserHomeDirectoryData?

Tags: iis-7, ftp, extensibility

I am able to set the FTP home directory based on username or site name.  Is it also possible to get the virtual hostname and use that?

It is possible to access this in IFtpLogProvider.Log using FtpLogEntry.HostName.  I just can't see a way to do it in GetUserHomeDirectoryData.

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: No answer to this, looks like it is not possible.